# Sum values on date table where one column equals a selected value from another

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a `DimDate` table that has a `Billable Day Portion` field that can be between 0 and 1. For each day that's in the current `Bonus Period` I want to multiple that Day Portion by 10, and then return the total sum.

To find out what `Bonus Period` we're in, I return `ContinuousBonusPeriod` where the date equals today:

```
Current Continuous Bonus Period:= CALCULATE(MAX(DimDate[ContinuousBonusPeriod]), FILTER(DimDate, DimDate[DateKey] = TODAY()))
```

I can see in the measure display this is correctly coming back as `Bonus Period 1`. However, when I then use `ContinuousBonusPeriod` in the measure to determine the number of days in the current period, it only returns 10, 1 day multiplied by the static 10.

```
Billable Hours This Period:= CALCULATE(SUMX(DimDate, DimDate[Billable Day Portion] * 10), FILTER(DimDate, DimDate[ContinuousBonusPeriod] = [Current Continuous Bonus Period]))
```

It appears to be only counting today's DimDate record instead of all the records where`ContinuousBonusPeriod = 'Bonus Period 1'` as I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make sure no existing filter was applied to the DimDate table when calculating the Current Continuous Bonus Period:

```
Current Continuous Bonus Period:= CALCULATE(MAX(DimDate[ContinuousBonusPeriod]), FILTER(ALL(DimDate), DimDate[DateKey] = TODAY()))
```

(Notice the `ALL()` statement)